# Backbone Collection 'add' event not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got an event listener in my Collection which listens for the 'add' event, which only seems to fire when the sample data I add in my router is added, but not when I add more models in my view, the code for both is below:

Collection:

```
Application.Collection.extend({
  name: "todos/todos",
  initialize: function() {
    this.on("add", console.log("added"));
  },
  url: "/todo-application/todos"
});
```

Router (this fires an event):

```
collection = new Application.Collections["todos/todos"]();
var m = new Application.Model({
    title: 'Finish screencast',
    done: true
});
collection.add(m);
```

View (this doesn't fire an event):

```
Application.View.extend({
  name: "todos/index",
  events: {
    "submit form": function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var attrs = this.serialize();
        this.collection.add(attrs);
        this.$('input[name=title]').val('');
    }
  }
});
```

The `collection.add` in the view definitely works, as the model is added to the collection and *displayed on screen*, yet the collection only gives me a `console.log()` on the initial pageload when the sample data is added...

EDIT:

According to my Backbone Chrome extension the event is indeed firing, but for some reason this event binding isn't working, and I have tried using `this.listenTo` instead of `.on`.

Comment: are you passing in the collection when constructing the view? e.g. `new View({ collection: collection})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `on` function on an object, you are binding a `callback` to an `event` on that object, and the `callback` must be a function, like this :

```
this.on("add", function() { console.log("added"); });
```